# Sass .scss: Nesting and multiple classes?

Tags: sass

I'm using Sass (.scss) for my current project.

Following example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container desc">
    <div class="hello">
        Hello World
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```css
.container {
    background:red;
    color:white;

    .hello {
        padding-left:50px;
    }
}
```

This works great.

Can I handle multiple classes while using nested styles.

In the sample above I'm talking about this:

**CSS**

```css
.container.desc {
    background:blue;
}
```

In this case all `div.container` would normally be `red` but `div.container.desc` would be blue.

How can I nest this inside `container` with Sass?

Comment: You should use a double class selector. This problem is a perfect example of nesting option in Sass. You can read all about that here https://kolosek.com/nesting-in-less-and-sass

Answer (score 795, accepted):

You can use the [parent selector reference](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector) `&`, it will be replaced by the parent selector after compilation:

For your example:

```css
.container {
    background:red;
    &.desc{
       background:blue;
    }
}

/* compiles to: */
.container {
    background: red;
}
.container.desc {
    background: blue;
}
```

The `&` will completely resolve, so if your parent selector is nested itself, the nesting will be resolved before replacing the `&`.

This notation is most often used to write [pseudo-elements and -classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes):

```
.element{
    &:hover{ ... }
    &:nth-child(1){ ... }
}
```

However, you can place the `&` at virtually any position you like<sup>*</sup>, so the following is possible too:

```css
.container {
    background:red;
    #id &{
       background:blue;
    }
}

/* compiles to: */
.container {
    background: red;
}
#id .container {
    background: blue;
}
```

However be aware, that this somehow breaks your nesting structure and thus may increase the effort of finding a specific rule in your stylesheet.

*: No other characters than whitespaces are allowed in front of the `&`. So you cannot do a direct concatenation of `selector`+`&` - `#id&` would throw an error.

Comment: Just a side note, a common use of `&` is when using pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes. For example: `&:hover`.

Comment: @crush For completeness' sake I added this to my answer. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I was being stupid as it isn't mentioned in the basics guide! BTW the docs has moved URL to: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector

Comment: If `&` is used at the end of a line, it puts that line at the beginning of the rest of the classes at all the other levels. You can combine elements by doing `&.desc` under `.container`, which would append .desc to it, resulting in `.container.desc`

Comment: scss-lint suggests to use "&::hover" (double colones)

Comment: @MarcelLange That looks like an error to me. `::` is used for pseude elements. `hover` however is pseudo-class and thus only addressed with a single colon.

Comment: and use in html : `<div class="container desc" >...</div>`

Answer (score 32):

If that is the case, I think you need to use a better way of creating a class name or a class name convention. For example, like you said you want the `.container` class to have different color according to a specific usage or appearance. You can do this:

**SCSS**

```
.container {
  background: red;

  &--desc {
    background: blue;
  }

  // or you can do a more specific name
  &--blue {
    background: blue;
  }

  &--red {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  background: red;
}

.container--desc {
  background: blue;
}

.container--blue {
  background: blue;
}

.container--red {
  background: red;
}
```

> The code above is based on BEM Methodology in class naming conventions. You can check this link: [BEM — Block Element Modifier Methodology](http://getbem.com/)

Comment: notice this sounds nice, but should be avoided at all costs. you will thank me in the future when you'll try to search your project for `.container--desc` and end up with no results.

Answer (score 4):

Christoph's answer is perfect. Sometimes however you may want to go more classes up than one. In this case you could try the `@at-root` and `#{}` css features which would enable two root classes to sit next to each other using `&`.

This wouldn't work (due to the `nothing before &` rule):

```css
container {
    background:red;
    color:white;
    
    .desc& {
      background: blue;
    }

    .hello {
        padding-left:50px;
    }
}
```

But this would (using `@at-root plus #{&}`):

```css
container {
    background:red;
    color:white;
    
    @at-root .desc#{&} {
      background: blue;
    }

    .hello {
        padding-left:50px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `&`

**SCSS**

```
.container {
    background:red;
    color:white;

    &.hello {
        padding-left:50px;
    }
}
```

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Cristoph's answer, if you want to be more specific in your declaration you can refer to all children of a container class component. This can be done with:

```css
.container {
// ...
  #{&}.hello {
     padding-left: 50px;
  }
}
```

This compiles to:

```css
.container .container.hello {
   padding-left: 50px;
}
```

I hope this be helpful to you!

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="desc">
    desc
  </div>
  <div class="asc">
    asc
  </div>
</div>

.container{
  &.desc {
    background: blue;
  }
  &.asc {
    background: red;
  }
}
```