# How to refer css style from another?

Tags: css

Here's the sample:

```
.my-class {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.my-another-class {
  /* here I want to include .my-class style */
  .my-class;
  border: 0;
}
```

Can I include one css class into another or not?

Comment: goo..... SCSS LESS SASS? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084757/sass-scss-nesting-and-multiple-classes

Comment: No, you can't do that in plain CSS. You can however apply multiple classes to any element.

Comment: You can set multiple selectors like: 

.my-another-class,
.my-class {}

Comment: Maybe you're not thinking this through... This is meant to be achieved by setting both classes on the element: `<div class="my-class my-another-class"></div>`. It would inherit both styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define multiple targets for the `.my-class` rule, then specify further rules just for `.my-another-class`:

```
.my-class,
.my-another-class {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.my-another-class {
  border: 0;
}
```

You can even then override certain properties, for example

```
.my-class,
.my-another-class {
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.my-another-class {
  border: 0;
  color: blue; /* overrides color: red; on .my-another-class */
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! That's I want. Could you tell me, is this a good practice to do this way?

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable, everyone does it all the time and I've never heard any good reason not to. SCSS or LESS are **better** options because they give you much more power, but they're also a lot more complicated. For a vanilla CSS solution, there's no problem doing this

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a construction like this in plain CSS.

Preprocessors such as [Less](http://lesscss.org/) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) support this behaviour with [mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature).

Answer (score 0):

You can't, but you can do something like this:

```
.my-class, .my-another-class{
  font-size: 12px;
}

.my-another-class {
  border: 0;
}
```