# Change jquery datepickers inline

Tags: jquery, css, sass

I using jquery datepicker inline.

I need to change `.ui-widget-header` class

Now it like this

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
```

And `ui-widget-header` has this style

```
ui-widget-header {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd/*{borderColorHeader}*/;
  background: #e9e9e9/*{bgColorHeader}*/ /*{bgImgUrlHeader}*/ /*{bgHeaderXPos}*/ /*{bgHeaderYPos}*/ /*{bgHeaderRepeat}*/;
  color: #333333/*{fcHeader}*/;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I tried to change it in my scss

```
    .ui-datepicker-inline{
    background: #fff;
  .ui-datepicker-header{
    background: #fff;
    .ui-widget-header{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #efefef;
    }
  }
}
```

But border is still not only at bottom.

Where is my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set the `border-color` property:

```
.ui-datepicker-header.ui-widget-header{
    border-color: transparent transparent #efefef;
}
```

Alternatively, it's possible that you could also set the `border-width` property, but that might shift the layout somewhat:

```
.ui-datepicker-header.ui-widget-header{
    border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
```

In pure CSS it would look like this:

```css
.ui-widget-header {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ui-datepicker-header.ui-widget-header {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: transparent transparent #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
```

Comment: I want to left only border-bottom

Comment: Yes, I understood your question.

Comment: But I cannot use it, with border-bottom?

Comment: That will only redefine the bottom border. The other borders from `.ui-widget-header` will still be in effect.

Comment: Probably also useful to take a look at the difference between nested classes and multiple classes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084757/sass-scss-nesting-and-multiple-classes