# Can't override Slick carousel style in Angular 6?

Tags: css, angular, slick.js

I have a carousel running with Slick and Jquery,
there's overriding style for the slicks dots (defined in the component)
However when running on localhost I can't see the slicks dots receive the CSS, it just loaded from the default slick css.

I checked the internal stylesheet rendered on the web: the default slick.css & slick-theme.css loaded before the component's css so it's supposed the component should have overridden the style but it's not working ?

Here is what I export in Angular.json

```
 "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          "node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.min.css",
          "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css",
          "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css"
        ],
 "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"
        ],
```

In my component SCSS:

```
@import "../../shared_scss/mixin.scss";
@import "../../shared_scss/variables.scss";

/* Slider */
.carousel{
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    .carousel_item{
       &:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
       }
    }
    .slick-dots{
        bottom: 40px;
        li button:before{
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        li.slick-active button:before {
            opacity: .75;
            color: $neon-green;
        }

    }
}
// responsive homepage carousel
@include breakpoint(xs){
    .carousel{
        margin-top: 40px;
        .slick-dots{
            bottom: 5px
        }
    } 
}
```

My component ts file :

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'slick-carousel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.scss']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    // Slick carousel
    $('.carousel').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      arrows: false,
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 300
    });
  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: There is an issue with your scss nesting. You need to write it like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084757/sass-scss-nesting-and-multiple-classes. Let me know if it helps otherwise I shall try it out myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you change the order of css/scss files angular.json as follow

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.min.css",
          "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css",
          "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css",
          "src/styles.scss",
        ],
```

and instead of applying style in component level, put the style inside `style.scss`, which will apply globally. Hence it will override the plugin style.