# how to use sibling selector css in styled

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, styled-components

I have a styled component which looks like:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';

export const CategoryList = styled(List)`
`;
//this is what i want to change
export const CategoryListItem = styled(ListItem)`
  border-top: 2px solid #f4f4f4;
`;

export const CategoryListItemText = styled(ListItemText)`
  padding-left: 5px;
`;

export const ListItemHeading = styled(ListItem)`
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
`;
```

How can I use siblings in this case & + & ?

I want to achieve something like :

```
li + li {
border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is done the same way as in SCSS with `&`:

```
export const CategoryListItem = styled(ListItem)`
  border-top: 2px solid #f4f4f4;

  & + & { // this will work for <CategoryListItem /><CategoryListItem />
    border-top: 1px solid red;
  }
`;
```

You can also style with html elements but the code above is a better practice

```
& + li { // this will work for <CategoryListItem /><li />
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

Basically you can do any nesting with `&`

```
& li { // this will work for <CategoryListItem><li /></CategoryListItem>
}
& li.test { // this will work for <CategoryListItem><li class="test" /></CategoryListItem>
}
```

You can read it up in the official docs:
https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#pseudoelements-pseudoselectors-and-nesting

Comment: Thank you for your time. Can you help me interpret this code? what does & and + mean and do?

Comment: `&` is the "nested parent selector" https://stackoverflow.com/a/11084798/4668136 . `+` is the "followed by selector" https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp . I have already described how the selectors will behave in your case in the comments