# Change css colors based on body class (dark mode)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have `<body class="dark">` and `<body class="light">`

I'm trying to edit css colors based on `body class`. **Is there a better approach than this**:

```
body.light .card {
  color: #292b2c;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

body.dark .card {
  color: #f7f7f7;
  background-color: #444;
}

body.light .jumbotron {
  color: #292b2c;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

body.dark .jumbotron {
  color: #f7f7f7;
  background-color: #444;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS Variables, so you will only need to set the property once

```css
:root {
  --darkColor: #f7f7f7;
  --darkBackground: #444;
  --lightColor: #292b2c;
  --lightBackground: #ccc;
}

body.light .card,
body.light .jumbotron {
  color: var(--lightColor);
  background-color: var(--lightBackground);
}

body.dark .card,
body.dark .jumbotron {
  color: var(--darkColor);
  background-color: var(--darkBackground);
}
```

Depending on the [support](https://caniuse.com/prefers-color-scheme) you'll need to give,  you can mix CSS Variables with `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`

```css
:root {
  --darkColor: #f7f7f7;
  --darkBackground: #444;
  --lightColor: #292b2c;
  --lightBackground: #ccc;
}

.card,
.jumbotron {
  color: var(--lightColor);
  background-color: var(--lightBackground);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .card,
  .jumbotron {
    color: var(--darkColor);
    background-color: var(--darkBackground);
  }
}
```

Comment: but how can I let the user select `prefers-color-scheme`?

Comment: The point of using that media query is to let the layout choose the scheme that user prefers. If you want to make a toggle for scheme then you can opt in for my 1st approach

Comment: oh, so the media query is kind of `magic-automatic`, meaning the browser decides what to show?

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme) - `The prefers-color-scheme CSS media feature is used to detect if the user has requested the system use a light or dark color theme.`

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so here's an answer instead.

If you're trying to make a 'Dark Mode' variant of your css you could use a media query to achieve this

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
/* override styles here */
}
```

More information on Mozilla's website https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme

The [casper theme for Ghost CMS](https://github.com/TryGhost/Casper/blob/master/assets/css/screen.css) is an example of a stylesheet that has a dark mode added to the bottom (section 12)

Comment: thanks for the link to the css file - it's really interesting to see their execution of dark mode!

Answer (score 0):

If it look like your example (same rules on different classes) just use comma to separate classes:

```
body.light .jumbotron,
body.light .card {
  color: #292b2c;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

body.dark .jumbotron,
body.dark .card {
  color: #f7f7f7;
  background-color: #444;
}
```

If it more complex then this example, consider using framework: [Sass .scss: Nesting and multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084757/sass-scss-nesting-and-multiple-classes)

Comment: thanks for showing the very interesting option of grouping!

Comment: looking through all of them and testing right now :)

Comment: @Yshmarov no problem. This is indeed a very simple solution for your question markup. Others answers here are more modern and fit to complex parameters.